# Does Google crawl domains with dynamic IP addresses?

Tags: dns, googlebot, ip-address, dynamic-dns

Does Google crawl web sites with dynamic IP addresses and dynamic DNS entries?

Comment: I've edited your post to remove the second question. Please ask only one question per post. Multiple questions may not each get the attention they deserve in answers, and it may be hard for other people with similar problems to find in the future. In any case, it looks like your second question has already been asked and answered here: [Is there some kind of API for submitting a site to Google for indexing?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28832/is-there-some-kind-of-api-for-submitting-a-site-to-google-for-indexing)

Comment: Looking for a dynamic DNS service, I ran into noip.com and one of the domain options is hopto.org ... Googled site:hopto.org and they are crawled. I would not expect great results but the answer appears to be in the affirmative to your question, with unknown limitations.  subdomain.yoursite.com with yoursite.com being static and the subdomain being dynamic may work better?